# Post HTML tag (codes) as string with ASP.net webforms & Extjs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, extjs

I am using asp.net webform to a json string containing html tags.
When i try to post data Console log error

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I remove tags from string its work fine.How i can post data with html tags in asp.net webform.

```
"{"SavePreview":[{"Recnum":"8",
                  "ScreenId":"1",
                  "ControlId":"label6",
                  "ControlType":"2",
                  "Value":"label1",
                 "TempValue":"<p>label1</p>"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Post HTML tags with asp.net WebForm you need to set `ValidateRequest` to `false`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TemplatePage.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Site.master"
    Inherits="Test.Web.TemplatePage" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```